# MySQL Stored Procedure fails to ROLLBACK on ERROR

Tags: mysql, transactions

I've attempting to rollback a transaction if any of the statements within the transaction fail.

The tables are InnoDB and the `SELECT 'ROLLBACK'` is triggered so I know the ROLLBACK should be too.

The transaction is not rolledback.  Any ideas why?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spTest;
CREATE PROCEDURE `spTest`(
    IN vUserID BIGINT,
    IN vSessionRef VARCHAR(50)
)

BEGIN
    DECLARE vUserSessionID BIGINT;
    DECLARE vUserSessionIDVersionCurr INT;
    DECLARE vUserSessionIDVersionNew INT;   
    
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'ROLLBACK'; /* This is returned so we know the error was triggered */
        ROLLBACK; 
    END;


    START TRANSACTION;
        SELECT UserSessionID INTO vUserSessionID FROM tblUserSessions WHERE UserID = vUserID AND SessionRef = vSessionRef AND isCurrent = 1 ORDER BY VersionStartDateTime DESC LIMIT 1;
        SELECT VersionID INTO vUserSessionIDVersionCurr FROM tblUserSessions WHERE UserID = vUserID AND SessionRef = vSessionRef AND isCurrent = 1 ORDER BY VersionStartDateTime DESC LIMIT 1;  

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpUserSessionCurr;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpUserSessionCurr SELECT * FROM tblUserSessions WHERE UserID = vUserID AND SessionRef = vSessionRef AND isCurrent = 1 ORDER BY VersionStartDateTime DESC LIMIT 1;
        
        /* This inserted record is not rolled back */
        INSERT INTO tblUserSessions (UserSessionID, EntityID, SessionRef, UserID, ValidUntil, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, LastUpdatedOn, LastUpdatedBy, isDeleted, isCurrent)
        SELECT vUserSessionID, EntityID, SessionRef, UserID, (now() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE), CreatedOn, CreatedBy, NOW(), 'spUserSessionCreate', 0, 1 FROM tmpUserSessionCurr;
        
        /* Deliberately using a wrongly spelt field name in the statement below to trigger and exception in order to test the rollback*/
        SELECT VersionID INTO vUserSessionIDVersionNew FROM tblUserSessions WHERE UserID = vUserID AND SessionRef = vSessionRef AND NOW() BETWEEN VersionStartDateTime AND ValidUntil AND isCurrent = 1 ORDER BY VersionStartDateTime DESC LIMIT 1;
    
        UPDATE tblUserSessions 
        SET LastUpdatedBy = "spUserSessionCreate", isCurrent = 0, VersionEndDateTime = NOW() 
        WHERE UserSessionID = vUserSessionID AND VersionID = vUserSessionIDVersionCurr;
        
        SELECT 'UPDATED' AS vStatus, UserSessionID, VersionID, EntityID, SessionRef, UserID, CreatedOn, ValidUntil FROM tblUserSessions WHERE UserID = vUserID AND SessionRef = vSessionRef AND NOW() BETWEEN VersionStartDateTime AND ValidUntil AND isCurrent = 1 ORDER BY VersionStartDateTime DESC LIMIT 1; 
        
        /* -------------------- */
        SELECT 'COMMIT';
        COMMIT;  /* In the even of a SQL Error, this point will not be reached */
    /* -------------------- */


END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I presumed that something within the transaction must be messing with the rollback, so looked at what didn't need to be in there, the `SELECT` statement near the end and the `DROP TABLE`.

Looks like the `DROP TABLE` was the culprit. I moved that outside of (BEFORE) the transaction and the rollback works fine.

Comment: yes, creating/altering/dropping tables can't be in a transaction; it will commit anything done up to that point and start a new transaction after

Comment: You don't need to drop a table if you're using the same name for a temporary table. The temporary table shadows the real table in this session.